# Angular Material - Dark Mode Changing Background Image

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Currently I have an app component that has a sidenav and my `router-outlet` in the sidenav content. In this component I manage the app theme by adding or removing the `darkMode` class in my `style.scss`.

Is there a way to control what background-image I'm using?

What if I also wanted to control the background image based on what component is opened on the `router-outlet`? Would that be possible to? Maybe not setting the background-image in the app component but on the opened component instead

##### app.component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-container autosize class="h-100">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-slide-toggle [formControl]="toggleControl"></mat-slide-toggle>
            </mat-list-item>
            ...
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
```

##### app.component.ts

```js
@HostBinding('class') className = '';
toggleControl = new FormControl(false);

constructor(private overlay: OverlayContainer, ...) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleControl.valueChanges.subscribe((darkMode) => {
      const darkClassName = 'darkMode';
      this.className = darkMode ? darkClassName : '';
      if (darkMode) {
        this.overlay.getContainerElement().classList.add(darkClassName);
      } else {
        this.overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove(darkClassName);
      }
    });

    this.subscription = this._service.currentLogStatus.subscribe(logStatus => this.loggedIn = logStatus);
}
```

##### app.component.scss

```
mat-sidenav-container {
    background-image: url('../assets/img/home-background.png');
}
```

##### style.scss

```
.darkMode {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($angular-dark-theme);
}
```

### Update

After some indications I've tried.

The `darkMode` background still presists on the ProfileComponent, even though I have another background referenced.

##### app.component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet (activate)="onRouterOutletActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

##### app.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleControl.valueChanges.subscribe((toggled) => {
      console.log(this.currentComponent);
      this.className = toggled ? 'darkMode' : '';
      
      if (toggled) {
        if (this.currentComponent == "home") {
          this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.add('darkMode');
          this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove('darkModeProfile');
        }

        if (this.currentComponent == "profile") {
          this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.add('darkModeProfile');
          this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove('darkMode');
        }
      } else {
        if (this.currentComponent == "home") {
          this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove('darkMode');
        }

        if (this.currentComponent == "profile") {
          this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove('darkModeProfile');
        }
      }
    });

    this.subscription = this._service.currentLogStatus.subscribe(logStatus => this.loggedIn = logStatus);
  }

  public onRouterOutletActivate(event : any) {
    if (event.constructor.name == "ProfileComponent") {
      this.currentComponent = "profile";
    }

    if (event.constructor.name == "HomeComponent") {
      this.currentComponent = "home";
    }
  }
```

##### app.component.scss

```css
mat-sidenav-container {
    background-image: url('../assets/img/home-background.png');
}

:host-context(.darkMode) {
    mat-sidenav-container {
        background-image: url('../assets/img/home-background-dark.png');
    }
}

:host-context(.darkModeProfile) {
    mat-sidenav-container {
        background-image: url('../assets/img/profile-background.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to maintain the `.darkMode` class and use different backgrounds based on what component is being rendered by `router-outlet`

### Solution

##### app.component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-container [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 
    'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0,' + theme + '), rgba(0, 0, 0,' + theme + ')),'+ 
    'url(../assets/img/' + currentComponent + '-background' + '.png)'}"
    autosize class="h-100">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-slide-toggle [formControl]="toggleControl"></mat-slide-toggle>
            </mat-list-item>
            ...
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <router-outlet (activate)="onRouterOutletActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

##### app.component.ts

```js
currentComponent: string = "home";
theme: number = 0;

constructor(private _overlay: OverlayContainer) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.toggleControl.valueChanges.subscribe((toggled) => {
    this.className = toggled ? 'darkMode' : '';
      
    if (toggled) {
      this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.add('darkMode');
      this.theme = 0.5;
    } else {
      this._overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove('darkMode');
      this.theme = 0;
    }
  });

  this.subscription = this._service.currentLogStatus.subscribe(logStatus => this.loggedIn = logStatus);
}

public onRouterOutletActivate(event : any) {
  if (event.constructor.name == "ProfileComponent" || event.constructor.name == "RegisterComponent") {
    this.currentComponent = "profile";
  }

  if (event.constructor.name == "HomeComponent") {
    this.currentComponent = "home";
  }
}
```

##### style.scss

```css
.darkMode {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($angular-dark-theme);
}
```

Doing it this way, I can control what image is shown and apply a filter when the `.darkMode` is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

> What if I also wanted to control the background image based on what
> component is opened on the router-outlet?

You probably need the *RouterLinkActive* Directive.

> Tracks whether the linked route of an element is currently active, and
> allows you to specify one or more CSS classes to add to the element
> when the linked route is active.

How to use it?

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" [routerLinkActive]="['class1', 'class2']">Bob</a>
```

To add the classes only when the URL matches the link exactly, add this option *exact: true*:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
true}">Bob</a>
```

More information and examples can be found in the official docs.
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

**UPDATE**:

To detect which component is opened / active , you can use (activate) directive of the router-outlet.

```
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
```

Based on that logic, you can change the background of the opened component.

Stackblitz with (activate) directive https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-dvsmnx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use this with my .dakMode class? Also how can I do that on `router-outlet`

Comment: Yes, I will update my answer.

Comment: I was able to achieve somewhat of what I wanted using this [style method](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles), but now, the only thing I can do is to change the background-image on `app.component`, I wanted to be able to switch background images based on what component `router-outlet` is rendering

Comment: updated answer^

Comment: I've updated my question also because I had some problems. Don't mind that if button is not pushed I don't set the background, this is just for testing different backgrounds in different components